# Tengo un problema al instalar una APK en mi dispositivo

Tags: kotlin, github, gradle, apk, jetpack-compose

El problema es que creo un fichero APK sin firmar desde el Gradle de mi proyecto de Kotlin en Android Studio, y hasta ahí sin problema.

Se me genera en esta ruta:

```
MiProyecto\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
```

Luego procedo a compartirla (Google Drive, GitHub, Apps de Mensajería, eMail...) para poder descargarla e instalarla en mi teléfono.

El problema es que cuando la voy a instalar (fuentes desconocidas permitidas), me pone que la app no se ha instalado, sin mensajes de error ni nada.

He probado a crear un proyecto vacío y seguir estos pasos y este sí me deja instalarlo sin problema.

Comment: Sin más información no podemos ayudarte. Incluye información como la versión del sistema operativo o nivel de API y arquitectura de tu dispositivo. Así como la configuración de compilación. El archivo `build.gradle` debería bastar. Por cierto, asegúrate de desinstalar la aplicación antes de instalarla. Puede que las dos versiones tengan diferentes firmas y al intentar instalarla como *actualización* falla.

Comment: @Mateo 
S.O. - Android 11
El archivo build.gradle a nivel aplicación es este:
https://controlc.com/9111d7d1

La aplicación está desinstalada antes de intentar instalarla.